# why isn't my AJAX get request working

Tags: php, jquery, post, get, xmlhttprequest

In my js page I want to get some variables from the php page using ajax(); 
This is all triggered by the html page load. I've tried to use both GET and POST, but nothing alerts or logs to my console like it supposed to, not even the error.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <script src="http://XXXXXX/bn/sample.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Welcome! </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

**JS:** (sample.js)

```
$(function(){

 $.ajax({
        url : "http://XXXXXX/bn/sample.php",
        type : 'GET',
        data : data,
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function (result) {
           alert(result.ajax); // "Hello world!" should be alerted
           console.log(result.advert); 
        },
        error : function () {
           alert("error");
        }
    });

    });
```

---

**PHP:**

```
<?php

    $advert = array(
        'ajax' => 'Hello world!',
        'advert' => 'Working',
     );

    echo json_encode($advert);
?>
```

Comment: Perhaps you haven't defined `data` yet?

Comment: Better yet, completely remove `data` since you don't seem to use it in your PHP file

Comment: does sample.php actually output anything?  Try going to sample.php by itself in a webbrowser.  If you see nothing or an internal server error then it isn't your ajax call.

Comment: And check what happens with Chrome console or Firebug..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the data you set at "data: data" ist the data u send to the php script. but u dont send any. the data you receive is available in you success function. so print it.
plus i removed the alert. alerts are lame. console rocks!

the " $(document).ready(" part starts your function as soon as your document is completlty loaded. i guess this is what you need and wanted there.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
 $.ajax({
        url : "http://XXXXXX/bn/sample.php",
        type : 'GET',
        data : (),
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function (data) {
           console.log(data.advert); 
        },
        error : function () {
           console.log("error");
        }
    });

    });
```

edit: remove the last comma, as your array ends there. you probably want to set a header before output.

```
<?php

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Content-type: application/json');


    $advert = array(
        'ajax' => 'Hello world!',
        'advert' => 'Working'
     );

    echo json_encode($advert);
?>
```

Comment: You need to explain what it is that you did.

Comment: you are working with a json file type, but the file you use to generate it ist a php file. the header tells your script that it is working with the requested json file.